# How to use a MCP23017 with MCP3008 for I2C voltage sensor with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi2, i2c, adc

I would like to know if is possible to use an MCP23017 16 bit I/O expander with a MCP3008 ADC and read the voltage with a Raspberry Pi 2. I want to use the ADC as an I2C device. I would like to do this so I don't have to run the program a 'root', so I'm thinking that running the ADC as an I2C device will fix this problem. I'm looking for help with how to wire the system as well as programming it. I'm using the Python 3 editor. The existing program I have will be used to plot a sine wave generated by a AD9850 DDS module who's signal is amplified and fed into a device. I want to measure this voltage. I know how to use a voltage divider, but am having trouble coming up with a way to read it. The measured voltage value needs to be stored as global variable that can be passed around the program. Right now I'm mainly concerned with not running the program as a root, turning the ADC into an i2c device, and storing the voltage as a global variable to be passed around in an existing program.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with any kind of I2C TO SPI converter. Still, you can use some I2C to SPI bridges if they work, I just googled it, but that can cause wiring problems.

I can suggest you the same ADC MCP series with I2C interface.Thus, the further I2C connections with MCP23017 expander and then the Raspberry pi would be easy.You can go through various analog to digital converters that can be I2C interfaced with their codes in python or java for pi like MCP3425, MCP3426, MCP3427, MCP3428. You can easily find them or also check control everything as that would be easy to interface using I2C cables and adapters preventing connection or wiring problems.For codes: https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=MCP34

The following codes for MCP_23017 can also help you code the way you want easily with expander being connected to pi:https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/MCP23017_16-Channel.
I think this would solve your problem!!

Thanks.